# Using ROW_NUMBER () to Compare 1st ARRAY to 2nd, 3rd, 4th, etc

Tags: sql, postgresql, row-number

I'm using `ROW_NUMBER` and I'm trying to compare `arr` in **rn 1** to `arr` in **rn 2,3,4**,etc
to see if they overlap.  I can do this with a **subquery / simple** **join**.  Is there a way that **AVOIDS** a join?

```
rn | id | job | arr    |desired_result
---+----+-----+--------+---------
 1 | 1  | 100 | {1,2}  | {1,2}
 2 | 1  | 101 | {2,3}  | {1,2}
 3 | 1  | 102 | {5,6,8}| {1,2}
 4 | 1  | 103 | {2,7}  | {1,2}
```

I made a [**dbfiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=6ca69ddd50c6c9fea754ad4219ca2e18)

```
--USING JOIN 
WITH a AS (
SELECT 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER by job) as rn
,*
FROM a_table
)
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT id,arr
FROM a 
WHERE rn = 1 
) x
JOIN a
ON a.id=x.id
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `first_value()`:

```
SELECT a.*, first_value(arr) over (partition by id order by job)
FROM a_table a;
```

`row_number()` does not seem necessary.

Comment: Great, thank you.  Didn’t know about first value - will help me a lot... adding link to documentation : https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-window.html